# Passing parameters to Airbrake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, airbrake

I am using the Airbrake gem v 4.3.8 and so far, it is working well and sending notifications and emails without issue. Here is how my code is set up:

```
begin
    # Do something crazy
rescue TypeError => e
    Airbrake.notify(e)
end
```

I do know that you can edit the parameters, similar to how airbrake records parameters by default when you don't use the notify method. I am trying to find the correct syntax for editing the parameters of an Airbrake notification / log.
I have tried something similar to this: `Airbrake.notify(e, parameters: {test: 'this is a test'})` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this doesn't work? Do you see anything strange in the logs? You should find those parameters in the Occurrences tab, inside the "Parameters" panel. By the way, I highly recommend to upgrade to Airbrake v5 because v4 meets its end of life in 2 months. See: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/issues/596

Comment: I. Am. So sorry for wasting your time, that solution actually does work, after refreshing my sidekiq server, it works like a charm. I apologize. Thank you for your answer!